# Setting an empty value for a text input

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS :

```
document.getElementById('sketchpad-post').setAttribute('value','')
```

The HTML input is as follow:

```
<input type="text" id="sketchpad-post" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Message"/>
```

If the second argument of the setAttribute function is an empty string, like in the example above, it doesn’t work : it doesn’t empty the text field (the text field has a previously set value).

Now if the second argument is a non-empty string, then, it works : it sets my text field to the provided value.

I find this behavior particulary strange…

I tried to enforce autocomplete="off" (and even autocomplete="flu") doing a setAttribute and also to do a removeAttribute('value') but I still cannot manage to have this field blank when the user display it.

As a workaround I can set the value to a kind of placeholder like '…' or whatever other character (an non-breakable space maybe?) but it’s not very nice.

I have this behavior in both latest Chrome (Chromium) and Firefox.

Any idea ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('sketchpad-post').value='';` ...?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Can you set up a snippet demonstrating the problem, or maybe a JS Fiddle?

Comment: @CBroe Thx a lot, it does work ! This is what I used first but for probably another reason it wasn’t working, so I then I came with setAttribute…

Anyway I’m still upset that setAtttibute('value','nonemptystring') works but not setAtttibute('value','') doesn’t (?!)

I expected e.setAttribute('value',foo) to be the exact equivalent of e.value = foo and it appears it is not the case when foo = ''. Weird.

Comment: @KevBot This is part of some other code and I can’t easily do it (modal content…) but you’re right. I may try to write a code that demonstrates this behavior…if I’m told  `e.value = foo` et `e.setAttribute('value',foo)` are supposed to be equivalent in *any* case I probably spotted a bug :\

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('sketchpad-post').value = "";
```

Comment: Yes thx @aquarium pain… As I answered to the other comments it works like this… I still don’t know why it doesn’t work with setAttribute. But I cannot manage to reproduce it in a snippet so… nevermind

Comment: @Stéphane by snippet do you mean like JSFiddle, if yes, https://jsfiddle.net/b8dvy7uy/

Comment: I mean I still have the bug in my application but I cannot manage to write a simple example to reproduce it. With simple code like the example you gave, or other things I tried, yes, it works.

Anyway, I have no more time to investigate on this as I have now a solution to my problem.